# How this cout will work?

Tags: c++, ostream

I am checking one code and getting confused by this line.

```
if( cout > 0 )
{
    //some statements
}
```

Please tell me if we can use `cout` like that. And how it will work?

Comment: my guess is this is a variable called `cout` not the `std::cout`

Answer (score 5):

`cout` is a variable of the type `ostream` (or some type derived thereof). The `ostream` has a conversion to `void *`(pre-C++11) or `bool` (C++11) - both of these conversion functions check for "error status" in the filestream, and return `NULL` or `false` respectively if there is an error). Both these will compare to zero as zero is the same as `NULL` and `false` respectively and thus the statement becomes `(void *)cout > NULL` or `(bool) cout > false`, which will be true if `cout` is not `NULL` or `false` (this means "has no error").

[Note: a pointer comparison with `NULL` may not work correctly when using `p > NULL`, since pointers may be "negative", in which case it isn't greater than `NULL` - I would prefer to see `if (cout != 0)` or `if (!cout)` as a safer/better choice].

Comment: `bool` is an integral type, so it'll be fine with the comparison (it being 1 if true). Unless you mean the part about it being explicit, because that will make it fail.

Comment: If `(void*)cout` is not a null pointer, `(void*)cout > 0` is unspecified.

Comment: @chris: Just updated to fix that - I thought `bool` didn't compare with `int`, but it seems that it does.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'm not sure exactly what `operator void *()` on `cout` returns in the case of "no error", and yes, if it's a pointer at a high address, one could guess that it's not going to work...

Comment: It typically returns `this`, but the standard just says a non-null pointer.  It will also typically work, regardless, since almost all compilers implement pointer comparison as unsigned comparison.  But the C++ standard says unspecified results, and the C standard says undefined behavior.

Comment: Interestingly, my minimal example with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` doesn't tell me that I'm doing something wrong... With `clant++` I seem to have some incompatible include files, so it bails out with some errors on the header.

Comment: Unspecified behavior doesn't require an error message.  In fact, the compiler isn't allowed to refuse to compile it.  You just can't count on any particular results.

Comment: Right, but "not require message" != "can't give warning"... There are lots of things that for example gcc warns for that aren't stipulated to give messages in the standard. Of course, some of those may simply be because the nobody could be bothered to write code to analyse it....

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` inherits an `explicit operator bool()` (C++11) or `operator void*()` (pre-C++11) from `std::basic_ios`. Both of these have the ability to be compared with `0`. However, each has a problem:

The `operator void*()` conversion will (thanks to James Kanze for pointing this out below) not be guaranteed to work as expected. The 0 will be converted to a `void *` as well, and then, since one is null and one is not, the comparison is unspecified (N3485 § 5.9/2).

The `explicit operator bool()` conversion will not be triggered in this context, causing that to not compile. However, I don't think there is any main library implementation that uses this over the `operator void*()` yet, even though they should. Clang might have this done for next release if it's C++11-complete.

Comment: The results of comparing a non-null `void*` with 0 are not specified.  So the code won't "work" (for some definition of work) in pre C++11.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Ah, cool. Is that only for `void *` and not other pointer types?

Comment: For all pointer types.  See point 2 in §5.9/2.  (This dates from
early C, although in C, the comparison would be undefined
behavior, and not simply unspecified.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, Found it, thanks. I never knew they were both converted to void pointers before comparing them, either, so thanks for that, too. I'll update my answer.